# Combinations of elements of different lists satisfying a condition

Tags: python, list, combinations

Here is an example of the input and afterwards of what I would like to achieve:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,6,8]
c = [4,7,8,9]
d = [4,8,9,10]
```

My objective is to find all the combinations of n elements such that the result contains one or more element of each list.

An example of result with n=3.

```
 res = [[1,3,8],[2,3,8],...etc.]
```

The only way I have found till now is using a comparison, for sure really odd and slow.

Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "find all the combinations of n elements such that the result contains one or more element of each list."   Are you saying you want each resultant list to include a one elements from the first n lists? What about repeated elements?

Comment: Think of making use of set operations. `e=set(a).union(b)`
`e=set(e).union(c)`
`e=set(e).union(d)`.  This gives a unique e set of values ` [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` and from there use your conditions. You can even do intersect and difference operations in set to get common and different values instead of iteration process and comparing one by one element.

Comment: @Varad a much more concise way of doing that would be `{x for y in [a,b,c,d] for x in y}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> all_elements = {x for y in [a, b, c, d] for x in y}
>>> all_elements
{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
>>> n = 3
# Find all n combinations of a set of the elements in all lists
>>> combos = set(itertools.combinations(all_elements, n))
>>> combos
{(3, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 2, 8), (3, 8, 10), (2, 6, 9), (3, 6, 10), (3, 4, 7), (2, 3, 6), (1, 2, 9), (4, 6, 9), (2, 6, 8), (6, 8, 9), (1, 8, 9), (1, 2, 10), (2, 3, 7), (4, 6, 8), (7, 9, 10), (3, 6, 8), (4, 8, 10), (3, 6, 9), (1, 6, 8), (4, 6, 10), (4, 8, 9), (6, 8, 10), (2, 6, 7), (1, 7, 8), (1, 6, 9), (4, 7, 10), (6, 9, 10), (1, 6, 10), (3, 9, 10), (1, 8, 10), (2, 8, 9), (4, 7, 8), (3, 6, 7), (1, 3, 10), (4, 7, 9), (2, 7, 8), (1, 3, 9), (2, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (2, 7, 9), (1, 3, 8), (2, 4, 6), (2, 8, 10), (3, 4, 9), (1, 2, 3), (1, 6, 7), (2, 7, 10), (6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9), (3, 4, 10), (6, 7, 9), (1, 2, 4), (2, 3, 4), (2, 9, 10), (7, 8, 10), (4, 9, 10), (6, 7, 10), (1, 4, 10), (2, 3, 8), (8, 9, 10), (1, 3, 7), (2, 4, 9), (1, 2, 6), (2, 3, 9), (3, 7, 9), (2, 4, 10), (1, 3, 6), (1, 7, 10), (1, 2, 7), (1, 4, 8), (2, 3, 10), (2, 4, 8), (1, 9, 10), (1, 7, 9), (3, 7, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 3, 4), (3, 8, 9), (1, 4, 6), (3, 7, 10), (4, 6, 7), (2, 6, 10)}
```

Here's the good stuff. This comprehension will keep only those combinations for which the condition is satisfied that every list in `[a, b, c, d]` contains *at least one* element from the combination:

```
>>> res = {com for com in combos if all(any(val in arr for val in com) for arr in [a, b, c, d])}
```

Check it out:

```
>>> res
{(3, 4, 6), (3, 8, 10), (1, 2, 8), (2, 6, 9), (3, 4, 7), (1, 2, 9), (4, 6, 9), (2, 6, 8), (1, 8, 9), (4, 6, 8), (1, 4, 6), (3, 6, 8), (4, 8, 10), (3, 6, 9), (1, 6, 8), (4, 6, 10), (4, 8, 9), (1, 6, 9), (3, 9, 10), (1, 3, 4), (2, 8, 9), (4, 7, 8), (2, 7, 8), (1, 3, 9), (2, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (2, 7, 9), (1, 3, 8), (2, 4, 6), (2, 8, 10), (3, 4, 9), (2, 7, 10), (3, 4, 10), (1, 2, 4), (2, 3, 4), (2, 9, 10), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 3, 9), (3, 7, 9), (2, 4, 10), (2, 4, 8), (1, 4, 8), (3, 7, 8), (1, 7, 8), (3, 8, 9), (1, 8, 10), (3, 7, 10), (4, 6, 7)}
```

Comment: Really appreciate. I try to implement in my code now. I'm working with list of tuples but I think the result would work as well. BTW, I'm sorry for the bad syntax, but you guessed correctly, I was looking for at least one element of each array. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Sure. Feel free to accept this answer if you're happy :)

Comment: This makes life easier than the set theory ☺

Comment: @Varad it's really not much different from using set intersections... it's just really easy to write this solution this way.